# GCE managed groups api for horizontally scaling kubernetes nodes

Tags: google-api, google-compute-engine, scalability, kubernetes

i would like to scale kubernetes nodes according to unscheduled pods. if i have pods that can't be scheduled because of their resource requirements, i want to add a new node to the cluster.

looking at autoscaling feature of managed groups in GCE, this doesn't seem to be possible, as their model requires a metric per node in the cluster, while my metric is global.

- can anyone confirm that this can't be achieved with current GCE solution?
- anyone know of any existing tool/blogpost whatever that could help implementing a solution?
- assuming i'm going to roll my own, i'm having problems finding an api that controls GCE managed groups (allows to add a node, remove a node)

thanks,
Nathan

Comment: this looks like an api i can use:   


https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/#resize_managed_group  


POST https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/zones/us-central1-f/instanceGroupManagers/example-group/resize?size=10

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with the standard per-node metrics, read the "Horizontal auto-scaling of nodes (GCE)" section of the [kubernetes cluster management guide](http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/cluster-management) to enable to autoscaler.

If you want custom metrics, you can check out the [GCE document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/scaling-cloud-monitoring-metrics).

There is also a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35572689/is-there-any-tool-for-gke-nodes-autoscaling-base-on-total-pods-requested-in-kube) on stackoverflow, and the author of one of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35762858/5265822) said that after writing their own custom metrics, the standard per-node metrics was found to be just as good, if not better, for their use case.